# how to pass the text in label to textbox

Tags: c#

how to pass the text in label to textbox.
I have login form that passing a username I input to label of another form
with a code

```
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
    frm2.Show();
    frm2.label2.Text = textBox1.Text;
    this.Hide();
```

In my second form the fix caption of label is Username

```
 private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = label2.Text;
    }
```

but when i pass the value of `label1` in `textBox1` the text is Username.
How can I pass it?

[image]

Comment: In the properties window in visual studio, there is a little lightning icon to display events. navigate to the TextChanged event (or another one, based on your preference), and double click the field to generate a code behind which will execute when the event is fired. In this code snippet, set the text for the label, as you have done for the load event of the form. Note. this load event should be removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Form_Load event happens before you set the `frm2.label2.Text = textBox1.Text;`

Pass the textbox using a new constructor for Form2

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
frm2.Show();
this.Hide();
```

in Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   public Form2(string username)
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       label2.Text = username;
       textBox1.Text = label2.Text;

   }
}
```

Comment: Theres an error in new "Form2(textBox1.Text);" say 'Windows.FormsAppliation3.Form2' does not contain a contructor that takes 1 arguments.

Comment: My fault, removed the void from the constructor line

Comment: There's one more "Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'WindowsFormsApplication3.Form2'; another partial declaration of this type exists"

Comment: Yes, probably you have the Form2.Designer.cs file that declares the class with the partial modifier. Just adding it solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in  "Shown" event, in the "Load" event your form hasn't initialized yet so your label' content is not "Mark" yet.

read this [Form.Shown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown.aspx)

something like this :

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = label2.Text;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have another problem that you should really address, besides just passing the username.  You shouldn't be hiding your login form for the entire duration of your application when you're not going to be using it anymore.  You'll also run into issues, given that it's your main form, in ending your application gracefully as your next form won't be the application's main form.

Instead you should ensure that the second form is the application's main form.  Go to the program.cs file and, instead of just launching the login form, launch the login form and then create a separate application for the main form, when the login form completes.

As for passing the information, simply create a property on the login form that can get the value of the textbox, and create another property on the second form that can set the value of it's label and textbox:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private TextBox textbox1;
    public string Username { get { return textbox1.Text; } }
}

public class Form2 : Form
{
    private Label label1;
    private TextBox textbox1;
    public string Username
    {
        get { return label1.Text; }
        set
        {
            label1.Text = value;
            textbox1.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Form1 login = new Form1();
Application.Run(login);

Form2 main = new Form2();
main.Username = login.Username;
Application.Run(main);
```

This is also a fantastic example of why forms shouldn't be exposing their UI components externally.  Only the form itself should be touching its internal controls.  By creating properties that allow information to be accessed or set you can ensure that the form properly reflects those changes in its UI without other classes needing to be aware of its internal details.